# Kotlin Android Studio Warning "Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders."

Tags: android, kotlin

I made a simple program to learn about concatenation in android studio with Kotlin. So, I tried to get a string value from resources in strings.xml as shown below and concatenate with a value

```
<string name="txt_show">Your lucky number is %1$s</string>
```

I got warning "Do not concatenate text..." from getString

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val firstNumber = numEditText.text

    processButton.setOnClickListener {
        val result = concatText(firstNumber.toString().toDouble())
        resultView.text = getString(R.string.txt_show, " ") + result.format(2)

    }
}

private fun concatText(myNumber: Double): Double {
    val luckyNumber = 1.79
    return luckyNumber * myNumber
}
private fun Double.format(digits: Int) = java.lang.String.format("%.${digits}f", this)}
```

By replacing

```
resultView.text = getString(R.string.txt.show, " ") + result.format(2)
```

with

```
val finalResult =  result.toInt()<p>
resultView.text = getString(R.string.txt_show, finalResult)<p>
```

And replace `%1$s` to `%1$d` in resources of strings.xml

The warning is gone but I got problems, first the result is integer which is not what I expected. It should be double. Second, adding the function format in getString will stop the program with "Unexpected Error..." message on the screen.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 23):

If you have string with some placeholders like:

```
<string name="price_string">Your price: %d</string>
```

### First you have to read this value and next fill it

**JAVA**

```
String text = getString(R.string.price_string, 2.5);
```

**KOTLIN**

```
val text = getString(R.string.price_string, 2.5)
```

.

### or in "longer" way:

**JAVA**:

```
// Read text
String priceString = getString(R.string.price_string);

// Fill it
String output = String.format(priceString, 2.5);
```

**KOTLIN**

```
// Read text
val priceString = getString(R.string.price_string)

// Fill it
val output = String.format(priceString, 2.5)
// or
val output = priceString.format(2.5)
```

If you have `%s` you have to fill it with `String`. Here you have more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings

Comment: how should I write it? I get it from web service (it's a number) and after that, I need to have a percent symbol.
it.data?.settlementPercentage.toString() + "%"

Comment: Try use: `%%`, so in text will be normal `%` char. E.g. `String.format("%s%%, discount)`

Answer (score 1):

> first the result is integer which is not what I expected. It should be double.

Then why did you call `toInt`? Just use

```
resultView.text = getString(R.string.txt_show, result)
```

and `%1$.2f` (or just `%.2f`) in the string instead of `%1$d` to format to two digits fractional number. You can see it's specified the same as in the `format` function in your code. The documentation for format strings (what all of these `%d` etc. mean) is at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html.

Comment: resultView.text = getString(R.string.txt_show, result) is not working when I use %1$d. So, I have to change it to %.2f and I don't need the format function to format to two digits fractional number anymore. Thank you.